# How to add html5 data- attributes to a rails form_tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, html, ruby-on-rails-4

How do you add html5 data- attributes to a rails form_tag

I know you can do this for a form_for tag but it is not rendering the same with a form_tag:

```
<%= form_for(@inventory, :remote => true, :html => { 'data-parsley-validate' => "", "data-parsley-errors-container" => "#inventory_errors" }) do |f| %>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to add html 5 data attributes to a ruby on rails form_tag add them inside a :data parameter.  So for the above question it would look like:

```
<%= form_tag("/inventories", method: "post", :remote => true, :data => {:"parsley-validate" => "", :"parsley-errors-container" => "#inventory_errors" }) do %>
```